# Commenting form with ajax not responding

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am currently programming a blog with a commenting system. I want to use AJAX so the page doesn't need to refresh after submitting a comment. 
However, the AJAX-process isn't sending the form information to my php-script. In my Javascript/Ajax-code, I have programmed several "breakpoints" using the alert-function to see what code in the AJAX-script is being executed. All of the alert-functions works fine, thus hopefully meaning that the AJAX-script is being executed. But no information is sent to my database.

Will you please take a look at my code below and help me figure out what I am doing wrong?

My HTML-form:

```
<form method="post" action="" id="commentform">
 <ul>
  <li> <label>Your name:</label>
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name" required> 
  </li>
  <li> <label>Comment:</label><br id="commentformbr">
  <textarea name="comment" id="comment" rows="3" wrap="hard" required></textarea>
  </li>
 </ul>
 <div id="buttondiv">
  <input type="submit" value="Post comment" id="submit">
  <input type="reset" value="Reset form">
 </div>
</form>
```

My AJAX-script (in the head-tag of the HTML-document):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#commentform').on('submit',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var name = $("#name").val();
        var comment = $("#comment").val();
        alert("After preventDefault");
        $.ajax({
            url: "commentsprocess.php",
            type: "POST",
            cache: false,
            data: {
                'user_name': name,
                'user_comm': comment
            },
            success: function(response){
                alert("Start of succces-function");
                $('#all_comments').innerHTML=response + $('#all_comments').innerHTML;
                $('form').reset();
                alert("End of succces-function");
            },
            error: function(e) {
                alert(e);
            }
        });
    });
});
    </script>
```

And finally, my php-script which should insert the comment and name of the commentator in a table called 'blogcomments'. The PHP-script also returns the latest comment:

```
<?php
include '../phpprocesses/phpfunctions.php';
require_once '../setupsql.php';

$connection = new mysqli($db_hostname,$db_username,$db_password,$db_database);
if($connection->connect_error) die($connection->connect_error);

if(isset($_POST['user_comm']) && isset($_POST['user_name'])) {
//get_post-function from phpfunction.php is used to sanitize the posted strings.
    $comment = get_post($connection,'user_comm');
    $name = get_post($connection,'user_name');

    //Inserts the comment in the 'blogcomments' table
    $query = "INSERT INTO blogcomments VALUES" . "(NULL,'$name','$comment',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)";
    $result = $connection->query($query);
    if(!$result) die($connection->error);

    //Returns the latest comment to the comment-page
    $id = $connection->insert_id($result);
    $query = "SELECT * FROM blogcomments WHERE name='$name' and comment='$comment' and id='$id'";
    $result = $connection->query($query);
    if(!$result) die($connection->error);

    $result->data_seek(0);
    $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    $name = $row['name'];
    $comment = $row['comment'];
    $time = $row['timestamp'];

    echo <<<_END
        <div class="commentdiv">
            <h4>Posted by: <?php echo $name;?></h4>
            <h5><?php echo $time;?></h5>
            <p><?php echo $comment;?></p>
        </div>
_END;
}
?>
```

Comment: Looking very quickly, don't put an 'action' in the form ... can you use developer tools to see what request is being submitted ?

Comment: @avrono seems same  page....;) but form is not getting submitted.

Comment: so remove the action and and then see ...

Comment: Thanks for your replies! I removed the action-attribute but still nothing happens. However, now I don't get the "End of success"-alert. 
Any more ideas?

Which developer tools do you suggest I use?

Comment: A bit confused. Did you check debugger (Chrome press F12) and see if your POST was succesfull in the network tab of the chrome debugger? You should see your data as part of your headers .. If yes then you can rule out one part and focus on the part which handles the sql insert (commentprocess.php)

Comment: Ah, now I am making progress. It seems the problem was my get_post-function in the commentsprocess.php all along. It's wierd it can't call that function since the url to the phpfunctions is correct. 
Anyway, this is a huge progress I haven't done for many hours so a great thanks for your help!

Comment: @MarcusHalbauer: Nice. Try using the debug tools of f.ex. Chrome (F12) when debugging. Often it will help you to narrow down where the problem occurs. In this case you would have seen that your data was posted correctly to your commentsprocess.php and make you focus on that part. Also make sure to post your answer to your question ..

Comment: Okey, it seems that the problem wasn't completely solved. When submitting the form, the input will be inserted in my database, but the comment isn't posted right afterwards. It will display after refreshing the page though. Both the input fields aren't reset to it's default value either.
If someone has a solution for this I would be very grateful to take a part in it =)
Else, I'll try figuring out and post my solution later!

Answer (score 0):

So, after getting your help and trying to debug things myself, I finally managed to get my comment page on my blog functional. You can see the rewritten and comments to the changes below.
My HTML-form. No more changes here than removing the "action"-attribute:

```
<form method="post" id="commentform">
<ul>
    <li> <label>Your name:</label>
     <input type="text" name="name" id="name" required>
</li>
 <li> <label>Comment:</label>
     <br id="commentformbr">
     <textarea name="comment" id="comment" rows="3" wrap="hard" required></textarea>
</li>
  </ul>
<div id="buttondiv">
  <input type="submit" value="Post comment" id="submit">
  <input type="reset" value="Reset form">
</div>
</form>
```

My AJAX-script. The changes made are:

1) The alert-functions have been removed and the url for the commentsprocess.php has also been changed (minor changes).

2) Instead of using "$('...').innerHTM L= response + $('...').innerHTML" to put the most recent comment first in the comment section, I have replaced it with the JavaScript function prepend() instead. This puts the response from the commentsprocess.php script first in the designated target.

3) Instead of using $('form').reset(), which apparently isn't working, I have reset both input fields in my comment field using $('#name').val("") instead.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#commentform').on('submit',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var name = $("#name").val();
        var comment = $("#comment").val();
        $.ajax({
            url: "../phpprocesses/commentsprocess.php",
            type: "POST",
            cache: false,
            data: {
                'user_name': name,
                'user_comm': comment
            },
            success: function(response){
                $('#all_comments').prepend(response);
                $('#comment').val("");
                $('#name').val("");
            },
            error: function(e) {
                alert(e);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

And last but not least, my commentsprocess.php script which handles the AJAX-call. This document was actually the main problem all along. The changes which have been undertaken are:

1) The get_post()-function from 'phpfunctions.php' was unable to be called. I replaced it with htmlentities() which sanitizes the $_POST-strings (I should sanitize it from MySQL-injections as well).

2) Instead of echoing the output, I just wrote it as plain HTML.

```
<?php
require_once '../setupsql.php';

$connection = new mysqli($db_hostname,$db_username,$db_password,$db_database);
if($connection->connect_error) die($connection->connect_error);

if(isset($_POST['user_comm']) && isset($_POST['user_name'])) {
    //get_post-function from phpfunction.php is used to sanitize the posted strings.
    $comment = htmlentities($_POST['user_comm']);
    $name = htmlentities($_POST['user_name']);

    //Inserts the comment in the 'blogcomments' table
    $query = "INSERT INTO blogcomments VALUES" . "(NULL,'$name','$comment',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)";
    $result = $connection->query($query);
    if(!$result) die($connection->error);

    //Returns the latest comment to the comment-page
    $id = $connection->insert_id;
    $query = "SELECT * FROM blogcomments WHERE name='$name' and comment='$comment' and id='$id'";
    $result = $connection->query($query);
    if(!$result) die($connection->error);

    $result->data_seek(0);
    $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);
    $name = $row[1];
    $comment = $row[2];
    $time = $row[3];
?>
<div class="commentdiv">
    <p><?php echo $comment;?></p>
    <a href="#" class="deletecomment">Delete comment</a>
    <span class="commname"><?php echo $name;?></span>, <span class="commtimestamp"><?php echo $time;?></span>
</div>
<?php
$connection->close();
}
?>
```